# How should I use fetch so I can parse the HTML, not json response

Tags: javascript

I have a simple page that fetches another page and prints/alerts/log. GET or POST , or document.write instead of mytext.innerHTML did not work either.
I want to get the whois details of URLS and display registrar URL, updated date and creation date.
I am using VScode. I do not want to use any framework like jquery.

```
   <body>
  <h1>Authors</h1>
  <div id="authors"></div>
  </h3>
  <script>
     var mytext = document.getElementById("authors");
     fetch(
     'https://who.is/whois/google.com',
     { method: 'POST' }
     )
     .then( response => response.text() )
     .then( text => mytext.innerHTML(text) )
     .catch( error => console.error('error:', error) ); 
  </script>
```

Comment: This won't work because the page you're fetching has its own `<head>` and `<body>`, has URLs that are relative to that domain, and has `<script>` tags. None of these things will work when put into the `innerHTML` of your own page.

Comment: Also, you're probably being blocked by CORS.

Comment: @Barmar How do I solve it. I want to avoid using any 3rd party js framework. This outbound call has to be from browser. It is a federated app - I dont have a http server. Please help I want to get  registrar URL, updated date and creation date from the HTML response clob.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Why don't you just display the site in an iframe?

Comment: @Barmar I want to display only 3 fields after some decoration, including finding difference between the dates. Can I do that in iframe?

Comment: No, you can't access the contents of an iframe from a different domain. But because of CORS, you can't fetch the contents of a different domain, either.

Comment: If you don't have a server, you can't do what you're trying to do. JS in browsers isn't allowed to access other domains.

Comment: @Barmar this is a static simple html page. I am not sure if CORS is applicable here.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be applicable? CORS prevents you from fetching from another domain unless the other domain sends an `Access-control-allow-origin` header that authorizes it.

Comment: @Barmar I have another working POC where a static page pulls information from some other domain. The format is JSON, though. Here in this case, I want to get HTML, parse it and take the fields I need. Are you saying it is impossible?

Comment: You can try. Check your browser console to see if there's an error message saying that it was blocked because of CORS.

Comment: Should be. InnerHTML = htmlCode. Not InnerHTML(htmlCode)

Comment: @MrZach I changed it, it is not working.