# Can I make a call to URL to fetch HTML in content.js?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Once I get active tab, I want to get the hostname and make call to icann.org to get the domain registrar. I Am having trouble making call from static html in the first place.
[Related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650094/how-should-i-use-fetch-so-i-can-parse-the-html-not-json-response?noredirect=1#comment110793322_62650094)

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts. Do it in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I am able to get the current active tab URL, say www.cnn.com, in content.js, how will I transfer the url to background.js so background.js can go to whois.com to get the expiration date of the domain cnn.com? I am not able to pass it to background.js. Since I am getting text/html mime type, does fetch work in background.js? fetch is not working on my local dummy html page I put together because i am getting to cross origin issue in my local dummy html page. I am able to get JSON response for my dummy html page for some other website. But whois.com does not give json response.

Comment: I can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve). Either edit this question or make a new one.